# How to remap control keys on windows server 2008 r2?

Tags: macos, virtualbox, keyboard, keyboard-shortcuts, windows-server-2008-r2

I am running windows server 2008 R2 inside VirtualBox on macOS Sierra. There is a standard PC keyboard (german layout) attached to the Mac and I installed a specific keyboard mapping so that it works pc-like in macOS. (strg (=ctrl on german kb) maps to command).

Inside the virtual windows machine, the keyboard works well too, except that ctrl now is mapped to the windows key, so that copy/paste becomes win-c win-v, which is pretty annoying on a development machine.

My idea is to remap these keys inside windows, but how? Or is there a better way to do this, maybe a VirtualBox configuration change?

Answer (score 0):

I found out the solution by myself, I used a tool called KeyTweak on the windows machine to change the left windows with the left control key. I also mapped the caps lock key to left shift, to get annoyed even less. Works fine!